# Multiple vertices between a node and one of its children

Tags: tikz-pgf, forest

I would like to draw several vertices between two nodes. Let's say that in the following code I want to draw

- 3 vertices between the start of the tree and its child O,
- and four between the first R and and its child T.

Here is an ugly picture showing the output wanted. This is only for pedagogical reason that I need to draw such a strange tree.

[image: An ugly picture]

It seems that `forest` can't do that. So how to di that using `tikz`'s functionalities ?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}
\useforestlibrary{linguistics}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{forest}
    for tree = {
        sn edges,
        grow'=0,
        l=2.5cm,
        s sep=0.2cm,
        anchor=west,
        child anchor=west}
  [
    [O
      [R
        [T]
      ]
      [T
        [R]
      ]
    ]
    [R
      [O
        [T]
      ]
      [T
        [O]
      ]
    ]
    [T
      [O
        [R]
      ]
      [R
        [O]
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What do you mean exactly? Can you show a picture of what you want? Something drawn in a simple drawing programme, for example?

Comment: However, whatever you mean, you should be able to adapt the example below to draw it. (Unless you mean something really strange, I suppose.)

Comment: @cfr I have added a picture.

Comment: So you want multiple *edges*? Vertices are corners, as far as I know. And you want them to start from different points? Should any of them start from the parent's anchor?

Comment: @cfr I don't know what is the easiest to do. If the vertices start from the same point, it will be good. I would like to be able to use "any" number of vertices so as to show how stupid it is to use this kind of probability tree instead of a weighted one.

Comment: So you want a stupid-looking tree?

Comment: No ! ;-) I just want to show some an inefficient way to draw probability trees.

Comment: Well, stupid or not, please see edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `edge path` from a node to its child can be as simple or complex as you like. If you can draw it, you can use it: curves, straight lines, whatever.

Do note that these are not 'vertices' of any kind, so far as I can tell. If they are, the usage is a highly technical one and will be widely misunderstood by anybody not versed in the relevant disciplinary language.

The diagram involves drawing many lines from a single vertex in the case that `connections` is set greater than `1`, but there is still only one point where the lines meet at the parent's `.parent anchor`. And if they did not meet there, there would be no vertex at all.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,multi,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\useforestlibrary{linguistics}
\forestset{%
  declare count={connections}{1},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={%
    sn edges,
    grow'=0,
    l=2.5cm,
    s sep=0.2cm,
    anchor=parent,
  },
  before typesetting nodes={%
    where connections=1{}{%
      if={isodd(connections())}{%
        edge path'={%
          foreach \i [count=\j from 0, evaluate=\noexpand\j as \noexpand\k using \noexpand { (\j==0) ? 0pt :((isodd(\j)) ? (\j*2.5pt) : ((-\j+1)*2.5pt)) }
          ]
          in {1,...,\foresteoption{connections}} { (!u.parent anchor) -- ([yshift=\noexpand\k].child anchor)  }
        },
      }{%
        edge path'={%
          foreach \i [count=\j, evaluate=\noexpand\j as \noexpand\k using \noexpand { (isodd(\j)) ? (\j*2.5pt) : ((-\j+1)*2.5pt) }
          ]
          in {1,...,\foresteoption{connections}} { (!u.parent anchor) -- ([yshift=\noexpand\k].child anchor)  }
        },
      },
    },
  },
  [
    [O, connections=3
      [R
        [T]
      ]
      [T
        [R]
      ]
    ]
    [R
      [O
        [T]
      ]
      [T, connections=4
        [O]
      ]
    ]
    [T
      [O
        [R]
      ]
      [R
        [O]
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: multi-edges]